# Mocked service class is not working as expected while testing controller with Guice

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework, mockito, guice

I have a controller that uses dependency injection and currently looks something like that:

```
class FormFieldValues @Inject() (ffValuesRepo : FormFieldValueRepository) extends Controller with ClassLogger {

    /**
      * Gets all FormFieldValue obejct for Checllist revision ID
      *
      * @param revId
      * @return
      */
    def getAll(revId: Muid) = Action { implicit request =>
        DB.withTransaction { implicit connection =>
            logger.info("INJECTED REPO: " + ffValuesRepo)

            val values = ffValuesRepo.getAllForChecklistRevision(revId)

            logger.info("VALUES: " + values)
            // Forse it to json
            Ok(Json.toJson(values)).as("application/json")
        }
    }
}
```

The actual execution of a controller works as expected.
However, when I am trying to build a test for with with mocked repository, the mocking does not seem to be picking up properly.

This is my current test:

```
class FormFieldValuesSpec extends Specification with Mockito{

    lazy val mockffValueRepo = mock[FormFieldValueRepository]
    implicit val connection = mock[Connection]

    val mockedServicesApp = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
        .overrides(bind[FormFieldValueRepository].toInstance(mockffValueRepo))
        .build()

    "FormFieldValues#getAll" should {
        "return a json object with all relevant list of field values for checklist revision ID" in new WithApplication(mockedServicesApp) {
            // Lets try an empty list first
            val emptyList = List()

            doReturn(emptyList).when(mockffValueRepo).getAllForChecklistRevision(Muid.fromString("r5R3m4MWQZVaKjCSikFJfg").get)

            val Some(result) = route(FakeRequest(GET, "/1/checklist-revisions/r5R3m4MWQZVaKjCSikFJfg/form-field-values"))

            status(result) must equalTo(OK)
        }
    }
}
```

In the logs I see this:

> 2016-01-15 20:34:50,450 INFO  c.w.FormFieldValues - INJECTED REPO:
>   Mock for FormFieldValueRepository, hashCode: 1337346192 2016-01-15
>   20:34:50,463 INFO  c.w.FormFieldValues - VALUES: null

Which means that the object is injected correctly, but for some reason instead of returning as per my stub (empty List), it just always return null.

**Update**
After some digging around I got it to work by replacing mock with spy:

```
val mockffValueRepo = spy(new AnormFormFieldValueRepository())
implicit val connection = mock[Connection]
```

So it looks like the mock itself simply didn't work...
How can I get it to work with a proper mock?

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: not much related, but just curious how you can define mock *mock[T]*. I need to use *mock(classOf[T])*  from *import org.mockito.Mockito.mock*

Comment: Well, that is exactly what I am doing, I think...